# Separate access logs from application logs with FluentD

Tags: docker, logging, kubernetes, fluentd

I have a Kong container in my k8s cluster which outputs all logs to stdout, so I have in stdout all logs mixed. Is there a way to tag the access logs based on a regex without excluding the other ones?

I've used:

```
<match kubernetes.var.log.containers.kong**>
  @type rewrite_tag_filter
  <rule>
    key log
    pattern /.*HTTP.*/
    tag access.log
  </rule>
</match>
```

But that seems to exclude any logs without HTTP in it, which leaves me without my application logs. I would like to keep these ones too.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! The way to keep the other ones is to have an extra rule to catch them, like so:

```
<match kubernetes.var.log.containers.kong**>
  @type rewrite_tag_filter
  <rule>
    key log
    pattern /HTTP/
    tag access.log
  </rule>
  <rule>
    key log
    pattern /.*/
    tag app.log
  </rule>
</match>
```